# How to make column in entity not available to read

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an entity with some columns. I want some columns to be not visible in json while getting data throw http request. But I want them to be present in result set.

So, I need them in result set while getting data from DB, but i don't want to see them in  responce json.

Comment: maybe `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, no, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the attribute or getter with

`@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`

It will allow you to write in the class but not read this attribute.

If you put `@JsonIgnore` it will ignore both (write and read).

Comment: It works with @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one class for different purpose with the annotation. Like I did

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "name") // for xml
@JsonIgnore //ignore for json
@Column(name="name") //db column name
private String name;
```

Comment: @JsonIgnore annotation doesn't work in my case, unfortunately